# SMTP_SSL SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib

This issue is related to smtplib's SMTP_SSL connection.

While connection with SMTP (without ssl) it's working.

While trying the same host & port in SMTP_SSL, error raised. The error is based on host only, The gmail settings also works fine.

Please check the below example and let me know if any changes needed for outlook & office365.

```
In [1]: import smtplib

In [10]: smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, timeout=100)
Out[10]: <smtplib.SMTP_SSL instance at 0x109ccaf38>

In [2]: smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587, timeout=100)
Out[1]: <smtplib.SMTP instance at 0x10a00bb90>

In [3]: smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587, timeout=100)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f0c5b0de4e24> in <module>()
----> 1 smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587, timeout=100)

/python2.7/smtplib.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, keyfile, certfile, timeout)
    794             self.keyfile = keyfile
    795             self.certfile = certfile
--> 796             SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
    797 
    798         def _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout):

python2.7/smtplib.pyc in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
    254         self.esmtp_features = {}
    255         if host:
--> 256             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    257             if code != 220:
    258                 raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)

python2.7/smtplib.pyc in connect(self, host, port)
    314         if self.debuglevel > 0:
    315             print>>stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
--> 316         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    317         (code, msg) = self.getreply()
    318         if self.debuglevel > 0:

python2.7/smtplib.pyc in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
    800                 print>>stderr, 'connect:', (host, port)
    801             new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
--> 802             new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
    803             self.file = SSLFakeFile(new_socket)
    804             return new_socket

python2.7/ssl.pyc in wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, ciphers)
    909                      do_handshake_on_connect=do_handshake_on_connect,
    910                      suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
--> 911                      ciphers=ciphers)
    912 
    913 # some utility functions

python2.7/ssl.pyc in __init__(self, sock, keyfile, certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs, do_handshake_on_connect, family, type, proto, fileno, suppress_ragged_eofs, npn_protocols, ciphers, server_hostname, _context)
    577                         # non-blocking
    578                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 579                     self.do_handshake()
    580 
    581             except (OSError, ValueError):

python2.7/ssl.pyc in do_handshake(self, block)
    806             if timeout == 0.0 and block:
    807                 self.settimeout(None)
--> 808             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    809         finally:
    810             self.settimeout(timeout)

SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

Ref URL: https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL

Comment: Does port 465 work for outlook.com?  587 uses STARTTLS and expects the client to negotiate a secure connection while 465 expects an SSL handshake right away.

Comment: timeout: timed out error for 465 port

Comment: Okay it looks like they don't support port 465.  According to the SMTL_SSL docs, `An SMTP_SSL instance behaves exactly the same as instances of SMTP. SMTP_SSL should be used for situations where SSL is required from the beginning of the connection and using starttls() is not appropriate.`  In this case, starttls is appropriate.  It looks like you should try just using smtplib.SMTP() and then calling smtpobj.starttls()

Comment: I understand your comments, May i know if any use of SMTP_SSL ?? Because we are using SMTP only ssl enabled scenario also ..

Comment: SMTP_SSL is required for port 465 since that is a strict SSL connection that expects an immediate handshake.  SMTP with starttls would be used for port 465 (and 25 if supported) where a TLS connection is expected to be negotiated after connection.

Comment: To understand which port and protocols could be used try: nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 465 this-is-your-site.com

Answer (score 7):

I have had this the same problem today and I have solved it.

This is my demo.

```
def _send_email(self, msg):
    if self.smtp_port == 465:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.smtp_host, self.smtp_port)
    elif self.smtp_port == 587:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(self.smtp_host, self.smtp_port)
        server.starttls()
    else:
        raise Exception('port {} not support'.format(SMTP_PORT))
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.login(self.from_addr, self.password)
    server.sendmail(self.from_addr, [self.to_addr], msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

**In my opinion** (perhaps it is wrong, just personal understanding.If sth wrong, please help me to fix it, thanks. ):

`465` and `587` is for different protocol. The former use SSL and the latter use TLS.They all use SSL to encrypt our email content before SMTP communication.

But for `587`. You must send `STARTTLS` first. If you don't do that you will get a message like this `Must issue a STARTTLS command first.` And for `465` you can't use tls command