# How to use SMTP with Apple iCloud Custom Domain

Tags: python, email, smtp, icloud

I would like to use Python's SMTP to send automated emails with a custom domain iCloud+ email address. However, I can't get logged into the SMTP servers. I will always either get "Mailbox does not exist" or "Authentication failed".

From the [Apple support pages](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304) it seems like you need to use SSL over port 587. Additionally, they want you to generate an "app-specific password" for outside applications. This led me to the following code:

```py
import smtplib, ssl

smtp_server = "smtp.mail.me.com"
port = 587  # For SSL

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

sender_email = "me@example.com"  # Enter your address
receiver_email = "you@example.com"  # Enter receiver address
password = "some,password" # app specific password from Apple ID settings
message = """\
To: {to}
From: {sender}
Subject: Hello There

This was sent through Python!
""".format(to=receiver_email, sender=sender_email)

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    # Send email here
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

However, this was still giving me a connection error. Only when I changed the last part to use TLS instead would it connect and give me an authentication error. This was taken from this question: [SMTP_SSL SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761676/smtp-ssl-sslerror-ssl-unknown-protocol-unknown-protocol-ssl-c590)

```py
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port)
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    # Send email here
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
    server.quit()
```

So how can I use my custom domain address with Apple's iCloud+ service with Python's SMTP?

Answer (score 4):

Just before I was going to ask this question, I solved it!

After reading [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/iCloud/comments/pkg1yn/smtp_custom_domain_icloud/), I figured that all custom domain iCloud+ accounts are actually alias of some sort to the main iCloud account. So, I tried logging into my "main" iCloud account. This worked with the above code and sent the email! However, the from was still not my custom domain email address.

This is a somewhat easy fix though, simply modify the "From: <sender>" line in the email body. I'm not sure if this should be done (since it's technicaly faking who you are) but it seems to work. If any email experts know of better ways to do this please comment/answer though! The following code is what I used:

```py
sender_email = "me@icloud.com"       # this is who we actually are
sender = "me@example.com"            # this is who we appear to be (i.e. custom domain email)
receiver_email = "you@example.com"   # this is to who we have sent the email

message = """\
To: {to}
From: {sender}
Subject: Hello There

This was sent through Python!
""".format(to=receiver_email, sender=sender) # this is what changed, we use an alias instead

# ...

server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Comment: I'm leaving this answer unaccepted since I wish there was a better way to login to my custom domain account without having to fake who I am.

Comment: Using my main icloud email as the username for the smtp request did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

1 year later, and I'm in this same scenario.

Tons of googling and I've finally found a solution. I wont lie I 95% ripped this answer from [chrisswanda on github](https://gist.github.com/chrisswanda/57fbc7c587f76d8437880657c0893009) so give them a star if this answer helps you.

Step 1: Create an App Specific password, especially if this code will be on a server you don't have full control of

Apple tutorial on app specific passwords: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397.

Step 1.5: Apple is .. silly.
I had to run the code below 3 times for this to work. Why? It kept giving me a `550 5.1.1 mailbox does not exist` error.

To fix this, all I did was enter the wrong password, which gave me a "Authorization failed" error, which told me that the account did exist, since if it didn't I should get the same `550 5.1.1` error back.

I then ran it with the proper password and it's worked ever since. Maybe their caches/indexes were out of date. I may never know.

Step 2: The code (I've formatted it for ease of use)

```py
import smtplib

# email.mime.multipart is specific to python3
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

custom_email = "abc@myfancydomain.com"  # This is your custom iCloud email
email_reciever = "generic_email@gmail.com"  # The mailbox you're sending the message to
icloud_email = "login_details@icloud.com"  # I used my apple default name@icloud.com here. My regular login email didn't work
app_specific_password = "secure-text-here"  # obvious

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = custom_email
msg['To'] = email_reciever
msg['Subject'] = 'iCloud has email!'
message = "It's true!"

msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.me.com', 587)
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.starttls()
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login(icloud_email, app_specific_password)

mailserver.sendmail(custom_email,
                    email_reciever, msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

Comment: Seems like you're using the default apple id to log into the server and then using a different email address in the "From" line? I think this is the same thing that I did; however, it sometimes caused my email to be bounced from Apple's servers and I would never get it in my to inbox.

Comment: @PrestonHager It's worked every time i've tested it so far, but I haven't used it in production yet. I think the `me@icloud` is just for authentication i.e I own this account. After then you can use any account `me@icloud` has access to, similar to how you change mailboxes in the iOS Mail app